# Google Drive API Uploading/Creating file (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the Drive API by following the samples provided [here](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c/). I've managed to download and list files just fine, but I'm having some problems with creating directories and uploading files.

When I try to upload a file (using the following code), no exception is raised but the file is not uploaded and when I debug the message I get for the request is this:

```
{Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File>.ResumableUploadProgress}
BytesSent: 0
Exception: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: baseUri"}
Status: Failed
```

The code:

```
...
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
        body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
        body.Description = "File uploaded by Drive Test";
        body.MimeType = DriveManager.GetMimeType(FilePath);
        body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = service.About.Get().Execute().RootFolderId } };

        byte[] FileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(FileBytes);
        try
        {
            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, body.MimeType);
            request.Upload();
            Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File res = request.ResponseBody;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
    else
....
```

And when I try to create a directory an exception is raised:

```
'request.Execute()' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException'
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
FileName: "Zlib.Portable, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=qwerty"
FusionLog: "=== Pre-bind state information ===\r\nLOG: DisplayName = Zlib.Portable, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=qwerty\n (Fully-specified)\r\nLOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/xyz/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/\r\nLOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL\r\nCalling assembly : Google.Apis, Version=1.9.2.27817, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=qwerty.\r\n===\r\nLOG: This bind starts in default load context.\r\nLOG: Using application configuration file: C:\\Users\\xyz\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication1.exe.Config\r\nLOG: Using host configuration file: \r\nLOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\config\\machine.config.\r\nLOG: Post-policy reference: Zlib.Portable, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=qwerty\r\nLOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/User
s/xyz/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/Zlib.Portable.DLL.\r\nWRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN\r\nERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.\r\n"
HResult: -2146234304
HelpLink: null
InnerException: null
Message: "Could not load file or assembly 'Zlib.Portable, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=431cba815f6a8b5b' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"
Source: "Google.Apis"
StackTrace: "   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in c:\\code\\github\\google-api-dotnet-client\\Tools\\Google.Apis.Release\\bin\\Release\\1.9.2\\default\\Src\\GoogleApis\\Apis\\Requests\\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 93"
TargetSite: {TResponse Execute()}
```

For the code:

```
.....
    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File NewDirectory = null;
    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
    body.Title = title;
    body.Description = "Descripiton";
    body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = service.About.Get().Execute().RootFolderId } };
    try
    {
        FilesResource.InsertRequest request = service.Files.Insert(body);
        NewDirectory = request.Execute();
    }
....
```

It's probably something with Zlib.Portable? But I'm really not sure what as I have the latest version from nuget.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it :)

A few things that I had to do:

1. Use the Signed version dll of Zlib.Portable
2. My Scopes weren't properly configured
3. Had to remove the existing credentials and log in again according to the new scopes

Comment: Used the Signed version dll of Zlib.Portable in every projects affected